# Shell script for automating Proftpd installation

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, centos6

I am stuck with creating a shell script to Compile and install proftpd in the centos server.  Uninstall proftpd from the server
Add and remove ftp users. The script should take username and home directory as argument. The password prompt should be securely entered without viewing.
The script should test that the new user can indeed upload and download files using passive mode of operation.

any help ??

Comment: Huh? You need a script that takes args like "centos -i" for install or "centos -u" for uninstall? Or do you need one that installs, then uninstalls, adds and then removes ftp users with variables set to users and their home directories? Please list out clearly what you need help with. At least start first as well. We're not going to write everything out for you.

Comment: I need following operations on pureftpd in a shell script 1. Compile and install Proftp. Create a ftp user onedomain who can upload files to /home/onedomain/public_html.
2. Enable passive mode and configure to use port 30000 to 35000 for file transfer.
3. The files saved in /home/onedomain/public_html should be of the ownership onedomain by default.
4. The user onedomain should be "jailed" to /home/onedomain folder. That is, the user should not be able to access files outside his home directory.

Comment: Why not just run the commands? It would be 10 times easier than scripting it as a lot of server work has to do with configuring specific files, your firewall, use permissions, etc.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.